# How do I fix windows giving out the wrong AD identity to my application?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

My application uses a Angular frontend paired with a `C#` backend.
For determining who's currently sitting in front of the pc, I use `C#/ASP.NET`'s `Current.User.Identity` .

Now, there is not a coding issue, my problem is that windows keeps handing out the wrong `Identity`. This happens since yesterday. My website keeps telling me I am `IISAdmin`, instead of my User Account that I am using right now.

I am guessing this probably stands in some relation to me adding a couple of network shares (quick access to the servers) using the credentials of `IISAdmin` and ticking the checkbox "Save Credentials".

Normally when I deploy patches I just connect to the server manually via explorer, and enter the credentials by hand. I have done this multiple times, this has never been an issue.

This is where it gets a little odd. I have tried starting `Chrome` explicitly as my User, and it just merged the window into the existing `Chrome` window I had already. Opened my web-app, `IISAdmin`.

I closed `Chrome` entirely, started it explicitly as my user again, `IISAdmin`.
Starting `Chrome` as a dummy account that I have access to, `Chrome` correctly opens a new `Chrome` window, and `User.Identity` confirms that I am logged in as said Dummy.

`Internet Explorer` behaves exactly the same way, so this is not browser-specific.

Even after a complete reboot this keeps remaining an issue. The network shares were removed after the restart, I am assuming they were temporary.

Windows should hand out my standard issue user account auth, not a highly powered super admin that's just saved somewhere.

Comment: Well IISAdmin isnt the user where your webpage is hosted?

Comment: @nalnpir I would like to clarify that this a client specific issue to me alone. Yes on the actual server it runs as IISAdmin, but this does not interfere with the Authentication for Users. I am positive that other users can use the application normally.

Comment: Perhaps this might be of use to you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff647076(v=pandp.10).  And you could give a try to the Thread.CurrentPrincipal()

Answer (score 0):

After talking to some colleagues, they pointed me towards the solution.

If this happens to you:

- Go to System Control / Credential Manager / Windows Credentials
  (Golden Safe)
- Delete the conflicting credentials

I was not aware of this at first, but when you create a network share and save the credentials, it saves them here.
What I didn't expect was that windows maps the file path to the server to the server's actual IP / DNS adress.

So whenever you connect to said server, Windows uses the saved creds it has, and because of the way Kerberos works, your existing token just get's handed around.

Hence making things a little mushy, even if you explicitly start Chrome as your normal user.